# Powershell Select-String output as CSV in 1 line

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string, export-csv

I am trying to get the output of `Select-String` into a single line instead of multiple rows but just can't seem to get my head around the same.

Here is my input string and an extremely simple pattern to pull out data after `'='`,

```
'trailer data      [REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119,STRTTIME=075257,STRTINTIME=671442647590,IMPIND=184,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9580=21,CSP_MS
_SRTIME_9210=24229,P4=9777A611236814D8,P7=04,CD=PT,S0=TestB82PTResponseTags,R0=00,R1=0FWEB8,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9560=24,]' | select-string -Pattern '=[A-Za-z0-9]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value.SubString(1) }
```

But instead of output displayed in separate line for each pattern searched,

```
0FWEB8

030119

075257

671442647590

184

21

24229

9777A611236814D8

04

PT

TestB82PTResponseTags

00

0FWEB8

24
```

I am trying to get output displayed as a CSV meaning something like this in one line itself,

```
0FWEB8, 030119, 075257, 671442647590, 184, 21, 24229, 9777A611236814D8, 04, PT, TestB82PTResponseTags, 00, 0FWEB8, 24
```

Tried using pipe to `Export-CSV` but even that failed.
What should be the syntax? I am sure its simple but can't seem to get my head around the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a little more simple as follows.

```bsh
"REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119" | select-string -Pattern '=[A-Za-z0-9]+' -AllMatches | foreach { $_.Matches.Value.SubString(1) -join ", " }
```

Comment: Thank you all of these answers are in fact correct as submitted by other contributors as well. I marked you as the right answer as I was able to expand your answer for a file-input easily...

Answer (score 0):

This is where -Join can be used based on the use case.

[about_Join | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join)

So, you mean this...

```
Clear-Host
('trailer data      [REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119,STRTTIME=075257,STRTINTIME=671442647590,IMPIND=184,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9580=21,CSP_MS
_SRTIME_9210=24229,P4=9777A611236814D8,P7=04,CD=PT,S0=TestB82PTResponseTags,R0=00,R1=0FWEB8,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9560=24,]' | 
select-string -Pattern '=[A-Za-z0-9]+' -AllMatches | 
% { $_.Matches } | 
% { $_.Value.SubString(1) }) -join ', '

# Results
0FWEB8, 030119, 075257, 671442647590, 184, 21, 24229, 9777A611236814D8, 04, PT, TestB82PTResponseTags, 00, 0FWEB8, 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your result to `ArrayList` then use `-join` operator to get desired output

```
$values = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList; 'trailer data      [REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119,STRTTIME=075257,STRTINTIME=671442647590,IMPIND=184,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9580=21,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9210=24229,P4=9777A611236814D8,P7=04,CD=PT,S0=TestB82PTResponseTags,R0=00,R1=0FWEB8,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9560=24,]' | select-string -Pattern '=[A-Za-z0-9]+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $values.Add($_.Value.SubString(1)) > $null }; $values -join ","
```

Output:

```
0FWEB8,030119,075257,671442647590,184,21,24229,9777A611236814D8,04,PT,TestB82PTResponseTags,00,0FWEB8,24
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I offer something original, but why not try it?

```
@('trailer data      [REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119,STRTTIME=075257,STRTINTIME=671442647590,IMPIND=184,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9580=21,CSP_MS
_SRTIME_9210=24229,P4=9777A611236814D8,P7=04,CD=PT,S0=TestB82PTResponseTags,R0=00,R1=0FWEB8,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9560=24,]' |
Select-String -Pattern '(?<==)[^,]+' -AllMatches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | ForEach-Object Value) -join ','
```

or

```
[regex]::Matches('trailer data      [REFNO=0FWEB8,STRTDATE=030119,STRTTIME=075257,STRTINTIME=671442647590,IMPIND=184,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9580=21,CSP_MS
_SRTIME_9210=24229,P4=9777A611236814D8,P7=04,CD=PT,S0=TestB82PTResponseTags,R0=00,R1=0FWEB8,CSP_MS_SRTIME_9560=24,]', '(?<==)[^,]+').ForEach({$_.Value}) -join ','
```

**Output:**

```
0FWEB8,030119,075257,671442647590,184,21,24229,9777A611236814D8,04,PT,TestB82PTResponseTags,00,0FWEB8,24
```

- The Operation statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6#description;
- The `ForEach` method:
  https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/12/10/foreach-method-in-powershell.aspx;
- The `[regex]` type accelerator: https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/30/regex-groups-with-powershell.aspx;
- The `Regex.Matches` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.7.2.